# Slide Out menu like eBay iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c

Does anyone know what method eBay use for their slide out menu in their latest iOS app - for the search filter?

The side menu comes out and is actually on top of the main view and shows its left edge as well (It slides out from the right of the screen. )

I am also not sure if they are just using a `UIView` or a actually `UIViewController`

Would really appreciate it if someone can give me some pointers here.

Comment: I have found a control to what I want - but not sure how to get the menu to come out on the right side of the view? Here is a link to it: https://github.com/mobivery/MVYSideMenu

Answer (score 0):

I eventually solved this problem.

Found a github project that has the `UIViewController` in `UIWindow` and it was a slide out menu. Only issue was that it was coming out from the left instead of the right.

GitHub Link: https://github.com/mobivery/MVYSideMenu

Following this SO question: [MVYSideMenu - menu on right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684226/mvysidemenu-menu-on-right)

Myself and @Harsh managed to edited it to a working solution.

Here is the same library modified to work from the right only. Along with working pan gestures:

https://github.com/TanderZA/MVYSideMenu

With some small tweaks, its 99% to what I needed.