# How to put the menu on the right in MVYSideMenu?

Tags: objective-c

I am wanting to use [MVYSideMenu](https://github.com/mobivery/MVYSideMenu)
for my new iOS project. It does exactly what I want - except for one thing. I want the side menu to come out from the right of the screen - not the left

I've tried changing the menu frame - but it doesn't change or breaks the sliding part of it.  How to get it to come out from the right?

Comment: There are a lot of other libraries which provide you the function of sliding form the left and right! Any specific reason for using this library?

Comment: The only reason I want to use this is due to the slide out menu being on top of everything else (In UIWindow) - the other libraries I have seen push the main view controller of screen. This is the only library I have seen that implements this. Do you know of any others? Thanks for the input.

Comment: Already noticed that... :P .. closely watching if i can customize this  one as per your need

Comment: Thanks! - I've been playing with it and got it to come out of the right of screen and had to modify a few things. I'd love to give you a copy of what I managed to do so far and maybe you have a better idea?

Comment: To add - its not behaving nicely at the moment as the code relies on it being on the left its finding out what needs to change to make it work properly.

Comment: yeah share a git code with me..

Comment: Let me upload it to my git hub

Comment: https://github.com/TanderZA/MVYSlideMenu-Right

Comment: Thats the git hub project I just created. In the example app - if you slide from right t left slowly it works - but you can drag the view controller more than it should go. If you swipe quickly it does strange things

Comment: made the changes and added it to the answers! have a look..

Comment: sorry! forgot to add changes for the pan gesture.. at present the project is working for tap gesture... committing the changes for that in a while...

Comment: Thanks. I did noticed that the pan isn't working. I'll look from my side as well to see what changes need to be made. I really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: If you run the example project in my git hub link - the pan gesture is almost there. But swiping quickly, breaks it.

Comment: Well you haven't committed the resource files of the sliding Menu, you have committed the files of your example! just commit them aswell so that we can have a look

Comment: Sorry about that I'll fix it now

Comment: I have made the changes to pan gesture and is working without any glitches! have look! :) P.S.: to my own repo!

Comment: My last commit added the rest of the files

Comment: Will look at your repo now

Comment: thank you for solution. I have one last question pls is it possible to disable the side view controller for some viewcontroller

Comment: [This link](https://github.com/harsh62/MVYSideMenu) was deleted from a link-only answer, and the poster claimed that this fork of the project fixes some issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try This ,I have added changes in existing **MVYSideMenu** the menu to come out from the right of the screen,

**Follow Steps:**

1) **Add code In AppDelegate.m file**

-Import this files,"MVYMenuViewController.h","MVYSideMenuController.h", "MVYSideMenuOptions.h"

-Add code in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOption{

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.

 MVYMenuViewController *menuVC = [[MVYMenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MVYMenuViewController" bundle:nil];
 self.homeViewController = [HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *contentNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: self.homeViewController];
MVYSideMenuOptions *options = [[MVYSideMenuOptions alloc] init];
options.contentViewScale = 1.0;
options.contentViewOpacity = 0.5;
options.shadowOpacity = 0.2;

MVYSideMenuController *sideMenuController = [[MVYSideMenuController alloc] initWithMenuViewController:menuVC                                                                                 contentViewController:contentNavigationController                                                                                                  options:options];

sideMenuController.menuFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.window.bounds.size.width * 0.75, self.window.bounds.size.height);

self.window.rootViewController = sideMenuController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

**2) Change in **MVYSideMenuController.m** **file only**

Sharing **MVYSideMenuController.m** function just replace with existing code.

**1) First Changes in function**

```
 -(BOOL)isMenuOpen {
  return self.menuContainerView.frame.origin.x == 
  self.view.frame.size.width-self.menuContainerView.frame.size.width; 
 //320- Added width as per screen size.
 }
```

**2) Second Changes in function**

```
- (CGFloat)closedOriginX {
return  self.menuFrame.size.width+200;
 }
```

**3) Third Changes in function**

```
 - (CGRect)applyTranslation:(CGPoint)translation toFrame:(CGRect)frame {

CGFloat newOrigin = frame.origin.x;
newOrigin += translation.x;
CGFloat minOrigin = self.view.frame.size.width-
self.menuContainerView.frame.size.width;//320- Added width as per screen size.
 CGFloat maxOrigin = [self closedOriginX];
 CGRect newFrame = frame;

 if (newOrigin < minOrigin) {
    newOrigin = minOrigin;
 } else if (newOrigin > maxOrigin) {
    newOrigin = maxOrigin;
 }
 newFrame.origin.x = newOrigin;
 return newFrame;
}
```

**4) Fourth Changes in function**

```
 -(void)openMenuWithVelocity:(CGFloat)velocity 
 {
 CGFloat menuXOrigin = self.menuContainerView.frame.origin.x;
 CGFloat finalXOrigin = self.view.frame.size.width-
self.menuContainerView.frame.size.width;//320- Added width as per 
 screen size.
 CGRect frame = self.menuContainerView.frame;
frame.origin.x = finalXOrigin;
NSTimeInterval duration;
if (velocity == 0.0f) {
    duration = self.options.animationDuration;
 } else {
    duration = fabs(menuXOrigin - finalXOrigin) / velocity;
    duration = fmax(0.1, fmin(1.0f, duration));
 }
 [self addShadowToMenuView];
  [UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
    self.menuContainerView.frame = frame;
    self.opacityView.layer.opacity = self.options.contentViewOpacity;
    [self.contentContainerView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(self.options.contentViewScale, self.options.contentViewScale)];
  } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [self disableContentInteraction];
 }];
 }
```

**Add below code in HomeViewControlle**

-In.h file import "MVYSideMenuController.h" file,

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) MVYSideMenuController *slideMenu;
```

-In.m file add below code ,

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad
 {
 [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
 self.navigationItem.title = @"MVYSideMenu!";
 [self addLeftMenuButtonWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_icon"]];
 }
```

Follow above steps you will see menu open in right side properly .

[image]

[image]

Hope this will help someone to open menu in right side by using **MVYSideMenu**

Comment: You are right but the animation of left to right still the same :(